# Is this the most efficient bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}²$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms

It is a known result that $\mathbb{N}$ can be put into bijection with $\mathbb{N}^2$. One example of such a bijection would be $f$, defined recursively by:

- $f(0)=(0,0)$
- $f(2n)=(2f_{n2},f_{n1})$, where $(f_{n1},f_{n2})=f(n)$
- $f(2n+1)=(2f_{n2}+1,f_{n1})$, where $(f_{n1},f_{n2})=f(n)$

So, for example, in binary notation, to calculate f(10110110):

```
f(10110110) = f(2*1011011)
    f(1011011) = f(2*101101+1)
        f(101101) = f(2*10110+1)
            f(10110) = f(2*1011)
                f(1011) = f(2*101+1)
                    f(101) = f(2*10+1)
                        f(10) = f(2*1)
                            f(1) = f(2*0+1)
                                f(0) = (0,0)
                            f(1) = (2*0+1,0) = (1,0)
                        f(10) = (2*0,1) = (0,1)
                    f(101) = (11,0)
                f(1011) = (1,11)
            f(10110) = (110,1)
        f(101101) = f(11,110)
    f(1011011) = f(1101,11)
f(10110110) = f(110,1101)
```

To describe it more casually, f "splits" the bits of the number into two numbers.

What I mean here by "efficience" is that, given $(a,b)$ from $\mathbb{N}^2$, as $f^{-1}(a;b)$ is at most $2ab$ it would have an "efficience" of $o(x²)$. There is surely a proper term for that.

Infinitely many other bijections exist between these two sets, but is there a known result about how "efficient" they can be? I can't find any that is better than $o(x²)$, is that the best possible? If it is, is there a proof for that I could read somewhere?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "majored" (mistranslation?).  But the [Fueter-Pólya theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fueter%E2%80%93P%C3%B3lya_theorem) seems relevant.

Comment: You can say "majorised by", but it it simpler just to say "is at most".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, suppose $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is any bijection. There are $(n+1)^2$ pairs $(a, b)$ of natural numbers satisfying $0 \le a, b \le n$, and since $f$ is a bijection, $f^{-1}$ applied to these natural numbers produces $(n+1)^2$ distinct natural numbers, at least one of which must therefore be at least $n^2 + 2n$. So it's not possible to do better than "$O(n^2)$" in the sense that we must have

$$\max_{0 \le a, b \le n} f^{-1}(a, b) \ge n^2 + 2n.$$